# Reference Object in Array List

Tags: java, object, arraylist, reference

updated question

Hello,

I currently have a problem understanding how Objects are referenced in Array Lists, or to be more explicit how using the get method of an array list really works.

I add 4 Objects to an ArrayList then I store a reference in "head" pointing
to the Object in the first slot.

```
public List<SmakeSegment> smakeParts = new ArrayList<>();

public SmakeSegment head;


public Smake() {
    addInitialSmakeSegment(14, 9, RIGHT);
    addInitialSmakeSegment(14, 8, UP);
    addInitialSmakeSegment(15, 8, LEFT);
    addInitialSmakeSegment(15, 9, DOWN);

    state = ALIVE;
    head = smakeParts.get(0);           // TODO: DEBUG check if reference gets updated automatically upon changing list entity
}

private void addInitialSmakeSegment(int i, int i1, int direction) {
    SmakeSegment segment = new SmakeSegment(i * TILESIZE, i1 * TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE);
    segment.addTileStep(direction);
    smakeParts.add(segment);
}

public void addSegment(){

    if( smakeParts.size() >= 2 ){

        SmakeSegment original    = smakeParts.get( smakeParts.size() - 2 );
        SmakeSegment duplicate   = new SmakeSegment(  original.getPositionLL().x,
                                                            original.getPositionLL().y,
                                                            TILESIZE, TILESIZE);
        SmakeSegment end         = smakeParts.get( smakeParts.size() - 1 );

        duplicate.setDirection( original.getDirection() );

        smakeParts.remove( smakeParts.size() - 1 );
        smakeParts.add( duplicate );
        smakeParts.add( end );
    }else if(smakeParts.size() ==1){
        SmakeSegment original = smakeParts.get(0);
        SmakeSegment duplicate = new SmakeSegment(original.getPositionLL().x,original.getPositionLL().y,TILESIZE,TILESIZE);
        duplicate.setDirection(original.getDirection());
        smakeParts.add(duplicate);
    }
}
```

later on I render the Object. The first object in list will always get rendered with an other asset:

```
public void renderSmake() {
    batcher.beginBatch(Assets.itemsUni);
    TextureRegion segmentRegion;
    SmakeSegment segment ;

    // cycle through the entire smake and draw its parts
    for (int i = world.smake.smakeParts.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        segment = world.smake.smakeParts.get(i);

        // first in array is the head
        if( i== 0 ){
            segmentRegion = Assets.smakeHeadAnimation.getKeyFrame(segment.stateTime, Animation.ANIMATION_LOOPING);

            // last in array is the tail
        }else if ( i == world.smake.smakeParts.size() - 1 ){
            segmentRegion = Assets.smakeTailAnimation.getKeyFrame(segment.stateTime,Animation.ANIMATION_LOOPING);

            // all other parts are middle parts
        }else{
            segmentRegion = Assets.smakeMiddleAnimation.getKeyFrame(segment.stateTime,Animation.ANIMATION_LOOPING);
        }

        // paint parts according to direction
        if (segment.getDirection() == Smake.UP) {
            batcher.drawSprite(segment.getPositionCenter().x, segment.getPositionCenter().y, segment.bounds.width, segment.bounds.height, 270, segmentRegion);
        } else if (segment.getDirection() == Smake.LEFT) {
            batcher.drawSprite(segment.getPositionCenter().x, segment.getPositionCenter().y, segment.bounds.width, segment.bounds.height, 0,segmentRegion);
        } else if (segment.getDirection() == Smake.RIGHT) {
            batcher.drawSprite(segment.getPositionCenter().x, segment.getPositionCenter().y, segment.bounds.width, segment.bounds.height, 180, segmentRegion);
        } else if (segment.getDirection() == Smake.DOWN) {
            batcher.drawSprite(segment.getPositionCenter().x, segment.getPositionCenter().y, segment.bounds.width, segment.bounds.height, 90, segmentRegion);
        }
    }
    batcher.endBatch();
}
```

now what really wonders me is that if I remove the first object:

```
public void removeSegment(int index){
    if(smakeParts.size() > index && smakeParts.size() > 1) {

        if (!smakeParts.get(index).getPixelMoves().isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < smakeParts.get(index).getPixelMoves().size(); i++) {

                if (index + 1 != smakeParts.size())
                    smakeParts.get(index + 1).addStep(smakeParts.get(index).getPixelMoves().get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    smakeParts.remove(index);
}
```

I had expected that an error would occur when rendering, since the "head" reference still points to the old object (SmakePart@4206) and thus will still be drawn although removed from the list since it is still referenced.

But what happens is that automatically the new first object in the list will be rendered. Debugging shows me that my "head" reference used in the renderer still holds the same object (SmakePart@4206) how can this be?
Is this SmakePart@4206 a pointer referencing my Object or is it referencing 
the first slot in the ArrayList, which is what I see here but then I wonder how to reference the Object and why debugging shows still the old Object, but draws at the position of the new one ( second before removing the first) also my list got smaller and one segment less is drawn. So it actually works as it is supposed to although I never update my "head" reference when removing the first Object.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Variables are not objects. Neither `testling1` nor `testling2` is ever the "original object"; they are both variables. The object is something else.

Comment: what do you mean the object is something else?

Comment: sorry, I cannot see anything, images cannot be compiled.... yet...  isn't it much easier to just copy&paste the code as text instead of making a screenshot? at least it would be much better to read!

Comment: better now... `testling2` is NOT a reference to `testling1`; it receives the same value, which is a reference to the instance - so both are *pointing* to the same instance

Comment: ok and why is it changing testling1 when I change testling2. and why is this behaviour gone in the end?

Comment: You have two `new` operators, so you are creating two objects. Variables are just references to those two objects. Let's call the first object `A` and the second object `B`. In the first part of the code, both `testline1` and `testling2` refer to the `A` object, so any time you change `A`, the value of `A` is changed (doh!), whether seen by dereferencing `testline1` or by dereferencing `testling2`. Later you create and assign object `B` to `testline1`. At this time, `testline2` still refers to `A`, so now they are referring to two different objects.

Comment: it is not changing `testling1` it is changing the instance that `testling1` was first pointing to (same instance `testling2` is pointing to). And nothing is gone at the end, just `testling1` pointing to another new instance

Comment: @Andreas ok but I never called testling2 = new...
So the Object A will be destroyed/ deleted when I set testling2 = null?
where is the Object A B saved, and where are the variables of them stored?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger ok I thought once the range of testling1 is exited, and once it is set to null, there shouldn t be anything testling2 can still refer to. I didn't realize that testling1 is also just a reference. So when is the original instance destroyed? and how do I copy values/obj without setting references to them.

Comment: *"So the Object A will be destroyed/ deleted when I set testling2 = null?"* It would be *eligible* for garbage collection *if* you set it to null (which you never do). --- *"where is the Object A B saved?"* In memory, on the heap. --- *"where are the variables of them stored?"* In memory, on the stack.

Comment: really not; otherwise no object would survive if a block ended... very hard for multi-threading... just `testling1` as variable stops existing, but not the instance it points to. An instance is eventually deleted if there are no (live) reference to it

Comment: @andreas if the object is only destroyed when there are no references left ( and thus get kicked out of the heap) when and how are variables of the object such as in my example "name" removed from the stack?

Comment: @railwanderer `name` is a *field*, not a *local variable*. The keyword used for when objects can be destroyed is **unreachable**. Can any code *reach* the object (somehow)? If not, it can be destroyed. If a `Testling` object becomes *unreachable*, it can be destroyed. Once destroyed, the string object referenced by `name` will likely become *unreachable*, and can be destroyed. Rinse and repeat. Of course, the garbage collector is smarter than that, and can destroy both at the same time, but that's a performance detail.

Comment: @Andreas and this class variable "name" or field is stored in the heap correct?

Comment: @railwanderer It is a member of the object and is stored as part of the object, and the object is on the heap, so: Yes.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks! totally makes sense now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here some important concepts:

1. objects are created with `new`
2. `testling1` and `testling2` are references that point to objects
3. `testling2 = testling1;` means that `testling2` is now pointing to the same object that `testling1` is pointing to, but they are still 2 different references
4. `testling1 = null;` means that `testling1` is not pointing to any object, `testling2` is unaffected, still pointing to the same object as before
5. objects are automatically destroyed by the garbage collector when there are no references pointing to them

I think this should be enough to understand what is going on with your code.